# Prove that odd and even subsequences are convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $(u_n)$ be the sequence defined by $u_{n+2}=\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}+\frac{u_n^2}{u_{n+1}^2}$ for $n\geq 1$.

When $u_1=u_2=1$, by using a calculator, I noticed that the even subsequence converges to 2.2287 and the odd subsequence converges to 1.8997.

When $u_1=3$ and $u_2=2$, by using a calculator, I noticed that the even subsequence converges to 1.9479 and the odd subsequence converges to 2.9384.

In fact, no matter which positive real numbers that I set for $u_1$ and $u_2$, the even and odd subsequences of $(u_n)$ converges (to their respective limits). I tried, rather naively, by back substitution to find the closed form in an attempt to prove this conjecture but failed due to the expressions being too tedious.

Would appreciate any insight, like some ideas of proof if the conjecture is correct or a counter example of positive $u_1$ and $u_2$ that disproves the conjecture.

Comment: Not an answer yet but something I noticed: let a be the even limit and b be the odd limit. Then a = (b/a) + (a²/b²) = (b³+a³)/ab², i.e a²b² = b³+a³

Comment: It's of course going to be easier said than done considering the given expression, but I think you should try creating a function $f : U := (0, \infty)^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(u_{n+2}, u_{n+3}) = f(u_{n}, u_{n+1})$, find the fixed points of $f$ and then try to apply the Banach fixed point theorem around those fixed points by looking at the Jacobian. There are multiple fixed points if the limits you found are correct so there will be obstructions to applying it on the whole domain of definition of $f$ at once.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: As a small reminder, don't forget to @ users you want to address. And no biggie, especially if it works out. Have a nice day otherwise!

Comment: @BrunoB Have a nice day!